# Using jackson mixin class for a list of objects

Tags: jackson, mixins

I'm having a problem deserializing the following json

```
{
      "GrpHdr": {      
 "MsgId": "Message-1",
        "CreDtTm": "2018-03-02T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]",
        "NbOfTxs": "1",
        "InitgPty": {
          "Nm": "Remitter"
        }
        },

  "PmtInf": [
    {
      "PmtInfId": "1"
    },
    {
      "PmtInfId": "2"
    }
  ]

}
```

I have created a MixIn class:

public abstract class CustomerCreditTransferInitiationMixIn {
    public PaymentInstructions paymentInstructions;

```
@JsonCreator
public CustomerCreditTransferInitiationMixIn(
        @JsonProperty("GrpHdr") GroupHeader GrpHdr,
        @JsonProperty("PmtInf") List<PaymentInstruction> PmtInf

        ) {

    this.paymentInstructions = PaymentInstructions.valueOf(PmtInf);

}

@JsonProperty("GrpHdr")
abstract GroupHeader getGroupHeader();

@JsonProperty("PmtInf")
abstract List<PaymentInstruction> getPaymentInstructions();
```

}

I'm having no trouble deserializing the group header in this case. Mapping different names. But in the PmtInf case I get confused. It is a list that I want to deserialize to a List of PaymentInstructions. But PmtInf is a paymentistruction.

I have created a test:

```
@Test
public void JacksonMixinAnnotationTestJsonIsoFileFromTester() throws JsonProcessingException, Throwable {

    CustomerCreditTransferInitiation customerCreditTransferInitiation;

    String jsonFile = "testWithShortNames";

    InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource(jsonFile + ".json").getInputStream();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = buildMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    objectMapper.addMixIn(CustomerCreditTransferInitiation.class, CustomerCreditTransferInitiationMixIn.class);
    objectMapper.addMixIn(GroupHeader.class, GroupHeaderMixIn.class);
    objectMapper.addMixIn(PaymentInstruction.class, PaymentInstructionMixIn.class);
    objectMapper.addMixIn(PartyIdentification.class, PartyIdentificationMixIn.class);

    customerCreditTransferInitiation = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, CustomerCreditTransferInitiation.class);


    //GroupHeader
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getGroupHeader());
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getGroupHeader().getMessageId());
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getGroupHeader().getCreationDateTime());
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getGroupHeader().getNumberOfTransactions());
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getGroupHeader().getInitiatingParty());
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getGroupHeader().getInitiatingParty().getName());

    //PaymentInstructions
    Assert.assertNotNull(customerCreditTransferInitiation.getPaymentInstructions());}
```

Getting the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "PmtInfId" (class
>   com.seb.payment.iso.domain.PaymentInstruction), not marked as
>   ignorable (19 known properties: "paymentInformationId",
>   "paymentMethod", "created", "paymentTypeInformation", "controlSum",
>   "debtorAgent", "instructionForDebtorAgent", "numberOfTransactions",
>   "requestExecutionTime", "debtorAccount", "creditTransferTransactions",
>   "debtorAgentAccount", "batchBooking", "poolingAdjustmentDate",
>   "ultimateDebtor", "chargeBearerType", "debtor", "chargesAccount",
>   "chargesAccountAgent"])  at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
>   (through reference chain:
>   com.seb.payment.iso.domain.CustomerCreditTransferInitiation["PmtInf"]->com.seb.payment.iso.domain.PaymentInstruction["PmtInfId"])

Answer (score 0):

In our case we have implemented our own deserializers in abstract iterable. 
On:
ObjectReader objectReader = ObjectMapperFactory.instance().readerFor(this.itemClass);

MixedIn classes are lost